# Auto-refresh loop on Pentaho report published to the Pentaho BI Server

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde, pentaho-report-designer

I need your help. I have designed this report using the pentaho report designer with two date parameters(DateFrom and DateTo). The report works fine when run on the designer and I've published it to the Pentaho BI Server. But on opening it on the browser from the BI server (CE), the reports is on an automatic refresh loop every 3-5 seconds. A glimpse of it, you can tell it has run correctly but the page refreshes almost immediately. Can't even change the parameters.

Has anyone ever experienced this and what is the solution?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Comment: This is only happening to the reports that I've created. I've re-published one of the sample Steel Wheels reports and it's not doing the loop auto refresh. Could be a configuration on my report designer?

Comment: Here's a link to a video snip of how it is behaving: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ad2jcnstf9w3jje/12-22-2017%208-46-35%20AM.mp4?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that the refresh loop is being caused by the date parameter. I removed the the date parameter and published the report with a static date and it worked well.

I will have to rethink of how to use the date parameter on the PRD reports.

I am going to post a new question on how to include a working date parameter on PRD and link it to this question.

In the meantime, I will consider this a closed issue.